# Unable to log columns text in a table (Protractor)

Tags: typescript, xpath, html-table, protractor, ui-automation

I have a table xpath like this

[image]

```
 element(by.xpath('(//div[@class='sprk-b-TableContainer'])[3]//tbody'));
```

I wrote a function which takes the webelement and logs the columns text

```
public logTableData(table: ElementFinder) {

        table.$$('tr').filter(function (row): any {
            row.$$('td').filter(function (column): any {
                console.log(column.getText());
            });
        });
    }
```

I don't know what I missed here it's not working, as I am new to protractor, can someone help me what's wrong with my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried like below, it fixed my issue

```
 public logTableData(table: ElementFinder) {
        const rows = table.$$('tr');
        rows.each((row) => {
            const cells = row.$$('td');
            cells.each((cell) => {
                cell.getText().then((cellText) => {
                    console.log('Failure Reason :: ' + cellText);
                });
            });
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`getText()` is asynchronous but you aren't actually waiting for the result to be returned.

Change it so that you are waiting for the text before logging:

```
column.getText().then(function(text) {
    console.log(text);
});
```

Comment: I added then to the function, still it's not working.

`public logTableData(table: ElementFinder) {

        table.$$('tr').filter(function (row): any {
            row.$$('td').filter(function (column): any {
                column.getText().then((columnText: any) => {
                    console.log('Column Content :: ' + columnText);
                });
            });
        });
    } `